# Método assíncrono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, async

Bom dia,
Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC 5 que faz abertura de chamados de TI, nela possuo um procedimento que faz disparos de e-mail para usuários no final da execução da tarefa (conclusão, abertura, encaminhamento, etc. dos chamados).
Preciso transformar esse procedimento de disparos de e-mail para assíncrono, e fiz isso. Mas não consegui fazer a chamada do procedimento na Action visto que a Action não é assíncrona.

Dessa forma, sei que a atividade de envio de e-mail continua não assíncrona. Para defini-la assíncrona tenho que definir a Action inteira também assíncrona? 
Não consigo apenas definir o procedimento?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DetalhaChamado(Chamado objChamado)
{
    // .. . AÇÕES DA ACTION
    if (email != null)
        Utilidades.Utilidades.EnviaEmailAsync(email.destinatario, Mensagem, email.nome, id_chamado); // DESSA FORMA, A ACTION CONTINUA A EXECUTAR A TAREFA DE MANEIRA NÃO ASSÍNCRONA        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um método async dentro do seu método e tente fazer a chamada, lembrando que seu método de envio de e-mail deve ser async:

```
    public ActionResult DetalhaChamadao(Chamado objChamado)
    {
        // .. . AÇÕES DA ACTION
        if (email != null)
            Task task = new Task(() => Enviar(item.destinatario, Mensagem, item.nome, id_chamado));
            task.Wait(1000);
            task.Start();
        async void Enviar(string destinatario, string mensagem, string nome, int chamadoId)
        {
            await Utilidades.Utilidades.EnviaEmail(destinatario, mensagem, nome, chamadoId);
        }
    }
```